# Is notification of fast forward rebase possible?

Tags: git

I'm trying to get a script to run when a git branch is changed. 
In this scenario, I have 2 branches master and deploy. I work on the master branch and I've setup a post-commit hook which handles changes to master.
 However deploy is a bit trickier, when I wish to deploy I rebase fast forward the deploy branch to master.

In this scenario there is obviously not commit occurring so the post-commit hook won't trigger. It would also appear that despite the branch changing the post-rewrite hook is also not triggering.

So my question is this, Is there anyway to run a script when a branch is rebase fast forwarded? (I would also like to note there are no remote's involved in this scenario)

Comment: What " rebase fast forwarded" would mean though? DO you mean the deploy branch is already on top of master? In which case, a rebase would be a no-op.

Comment: deploy is several commits behind master and contains no unique commits. it is fast forwarded to master. I may be using the wrong term but the fast forward option is presented under the tortoisegit rebase menu